# Custom Exception that wraps Multiple Exceptions : Encouraged or Not?

Tags: java, jar, exception, checked-exceptions

I am coding a Java Library that will be used to access a DB.
I am throwing the exceptions to the end-programmer who uses the JAR library to handle it the way he/she wants.

I wrote a custom Exception (provided below) to wrap connection specific exceptions together so the end-programmer will not have to catch all these exceptions in his code. (to make it easy for him)

is this a good practice when it comes to coding Java libraries? 
By using this the user will only have to catch NConnectionException in his code.

```
public class NConnectionException extends Exception {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NConnectionException.class);
public NConnectionException(Exception e) {

    if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {
        logger.error("ERROR IN READING DF");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    else if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        logger.error("FILE NOT FOUND");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } else if (e instanceof ParserConfigurationException)
    {
        logger.error("PARSE CONF ERR");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    else if (e instanceof org.xml.sax.SAXException)
    {
        logger.error("SAX ERR");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    else if (e instanceof IOException)
    {
        logger.error("IO ERR");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: In your case your are not storing any stack trace or error message in your custom exception. Using `e.printStackTrace();` is a bad practice.

Comment: You can store multiple exception in a list inside your `NConnectionException`, and let your calling program decide what data it require from the exception. I would suggest not to handle runtime exception i.e. unchecked exceptions.

Comment: And by doing so I have to iterate through the exception list and find which exception that is thrown? Or haven't I understood what you said correctly?  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: And instead of printing the stack trace I threw the exception object. Is that encouraged?

Comment: Yes, calling program need to iterate through it. Does your program throws multiple exceptions `at a time`? As this will occur only in multithreaded environment.

Comment: Yes, It can. Will that be a problem?

Comment: I mean to say, does your program throws `NullPointerException` as well as `FileNotFoundException` for a single call? Or it will throw one of them in a single call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74893/discussion-between-ndnine89-and-naman-gala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23223819/3898076) post, wrapping all the exceptions in a single is not good.

---

If you want to wrap them then

As your program will throw only one exception at a time then no need to store list of exceptions in `NConnectionException`.

And you can create a single object of exception in NConnectionException class. You can refer [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27633772/3898076) structure.

And store the thrown exception in that object and throw back newly created object of `NConnectionException` class. Let the calling program catch NConnectionException exception and take out the stored object and act accordingly.

**Note** : Generally we don't handle unchecked exception (like NullPointerException), calling program will take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a cause (Throwable) to a custom exception. Look at the [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) javadoc for more Information.

Edit:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    public CustomException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
    }
}

public void testMethod(String s) throws CustomException {
   try {
       int integer = Integer.parseInt(s);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       throw new CustomException(e);
   }
}

try {
    testMethod("not a number");
} catch (CustomException ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace(); // this will print that a CustomException
                          // with the cause NumberFormatException has occured.
    ce.getCause(); // this will return the cause that
                   // we set in the catch clause in the method testMethod
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I used this constructor , public Exception(String message,Throwable cause) and threw the cause to my customException.
I am unclear what the next step is. Would you please elaborate.

Comment: I added a example for you